# SSIS - Source Assistant is not showing the Project Level Connections

Tags: ssis, connection, database-connection, oledbconnection

I have created an OLE DB  connection to project level (Native OLE DB\SQL Server Native Client 11.0). When I try to use it from the Source Assistant,  I can not see it on the list. However, If I choose an OLE DB Source Connection, this is available without any issue.

What could be happening?

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.4.2.

Comment: Exactly the same problem with VS 2017.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I was hoping someone would answer this. Actually, it's not recognizing a project connection changed to a package connection either.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a great answer, but I have found a work around.

I create a package level connection and then go back and edit the Source Assistant.  At that time, I am able to see the project connection.  I change it to the project connection and then delete the package connection.

It isn't ideal, but until I can find a way to fix this, I'm using this workaround.

Comment: var s = nameof(answeredUser);
s[3] = 'e';

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it like this:

Create your Source Assistant with some empty connection string, for example just put a dot (.) as your server name and click Ok.
Then open your Source Assistant and your project level connections should be under the OLE DB connection manager dropdown .